# Hackerrank Python Requests ConnectionError

Tags: python, connection, runtime-error

I had a HackerRank REST API challenge, where I used Python to make a request to the indicated hackerrank api, but in HackerRank it kept (and keeps) raising a requests.exceptions.ConnectionError.
I have isolated the error from any HackerRank challenge editor window to this minimal test code:

```
import requests
response = requests.get("https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/moviesdata")
print(response)
```

This works ok from my computer, giving 200 response status code, but from Hackerrank it gives this runtime error.
Any idea if hackerrank blocks connections? Or should I have used any other python library?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 157, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/usr/local/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 61, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/local/lib-python/3/socket.py", line 743, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
_socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/usr/local/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 334, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/usr/local/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 169, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000001f00bb8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 720, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/usr/local/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 436, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='jsonmock.hackerrank.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/moviesdata (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000001f00bb8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='jsonmock.hackerrank.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/moviesdata (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000000001f00bb8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution',))
```

Comment: Did you see the error message? "Temporary failure in name resolution" --- hackerrank has DNS problems. Nothing you can do about that. Wait and try again later.